# what to do fix layout in running app?

Tags: android

I have this layout activity it contains some EditTexts and Button and TextView but I have a problem,  nothing appear on the emulator except the TextView "Already Registered? sign in" and the other things doesn't appear on the activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mohamed.myawesomeapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailReg"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Enter your email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pssReg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.849" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pssReg"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/regReg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/regReg"
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signinReg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signinReg"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Already Registered? sign in"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="207dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

it is ok in the design, when I run the app, nothing appear on the emulator except the TextView "Already Registered? sign in" and the other things doesn't appear on the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put password EditText on the bottom of email EditText, use `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`. It will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mohamed.myawesomeapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailReg"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Enter your email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pssReg"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailReg"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/regReg"
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pssReg"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signinReg"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Already Registered? sign in"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regReg"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Editing with @Pakeeza's suggestion)

Use relative layout or linear layout instead of constraint layout. You can change layout type in xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.practiceset2.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailReg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="Enter your email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pssReg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:hint="Enter your password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/regReg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Register"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/signinReg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Already Registered? sign in"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" /> </LinearLayout>
```